# How to run specific version (8.4, 9.1) of postgresql pg_* command (e.g., pg_dump)

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I have Postgresql versions 8.4 and 9.1 installed.  For any given Postgresql command, how do I specify a specific version of the command to run?  (e.g., `psql`, `pg_dump`, `pg_ctlcluster`, `pg_restore`, ...)

My question is motivated by wanting to do a pg_dump in preparation for an upgrade from 8.4 to 9.1, and I want to know which pg_dump version I am running.

I'm running on Ubuntu 10.04 Natty.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are on Ubuntu and obviously have Martin Pitt's `pg_wrapper` installed (judging from `pg_ctlcluster`) that is provided by the package [`postgresql-common`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/postgresql-common) and comes with the standard Debian packages. I use [the same on Debian](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/postgresql-common).

On a Linux system, run `which` in the shell to see which executable is actually picked:

```sh
postgres@db:~$ which pg_dump
/usr/bin/pg_dump
postgres@db:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/pg_dump
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37  4. Jun 18:57 /usr/bin/pg_dump -> ../share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper
```

`pg_dump` is actually a symlink to `pg_wrapper`, which dynamically picks the appropriate version of the client program for the db cluster you run `pg_dump` with. I quote the man page of `pg_wrapper`:

> This program is run only as a link to names which correspond to PostgreSQL programs in /usr/lib/postgresql/version/bin. It determines
>   the configured cluster and
>          database for the user and calls the appropriate version of the desired program to connect to that cluster and database, supplying any
>   specified options to that command.
>
> ```
>    The target cluster is selected by the following means, in descending order of precedence:
>    1.  explicit specification with the --cluster option
>    2.  explicit specification with the PGCLUSTER environment variable
>    3.  matching entry in ~/.postgresqlrc (see postgresqlrc(5)), if that file exists
>    4.  matching entry in /etc/postgresql-common/user_clusters (see user_clusters(5)), if that file exists
>    5.  If only one local cluster exists, that one will be selected.
>    6.  If several local clusters exist, the one listening on the default port 5432 will be selected.
>
>    If none of these rules match, pg_wrapper aborts with an error.
> ```

IOW, the right version should be picked automagically - unless you screwed up your installation somehow. You can always add the option `--cluster` to be specific.

Comment: Just a note: this doesn't help with remote connections. I have 8.3 and 9.1 client tools installed and it defaults to 8.3 for some reason. I have to manually select the path in /usr/lib to use the correct version. I would've thought that the newest one would be used by default, but seems not.

Comment: You do not need the newest one, but the one matching your database. For *some* purposes the new version of pg_dump may be the better option, though.

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly needs to go in the ~/.postgreslqrc file? My client output -->
psql (8.4.21, server 9.1.13)
WARNING: psql version 8.4, server version 9.1.
         Some psql features might not work.

Comment: That does not seem to work for me. I created a dump on a server with 9.1, and when I tried to restore on another server with 9.1 and 8.4, it tells me it cannot recognize the file format. Also, there is no `--cluster` command line option.

Answer (score 5):

I use

```
PGCLUSTER=8.4/main pg_dump ...
PGCLUSTER=9.1/main pg_dump ...
```

Answer (score 0):

previous solutions does not worker for me on Debian buster and uppper. I ended up creating by own scripts which should replace binaries installed into `/usr/bin/` from package.

here's script for pg_dump

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echoerr() { echo "$@" 1>&2; }

pg_version_file="./.pg_version"
default_version="12"

if [ -f "$pg_version_file" ]; then
        # echo "pg_version file found $pg_version_file with version $(cat $pg_version_file)"
        default_version=$(cat $pg_version_file)
# else
        # echo "pg_version file not found. default version is $default_version"
fi

version=${PG_VERSION:-$default_version}
valid_versions="9.3 9.4 9.5 9.6 10 11 12 13"

if [[ ! " $valid_versions " =~ .*\ $version\ .* ]]
then
        echoerr "Invalid version $version"
        echoerr "Should be one of $valid_versions"
        exit -1
fi

pg_dump="/usr/lib/postgresql/$version/bin/pg_dump"

if [ ! -f "$pg_dump" ]; then
        echoerr "File $pg_dump not found!"
        exit -1
fi

# echo "use version $version"

"$pg_dump" "$@"
```

I hope it will be useful for someone. Just change pg_dump to psql or any other version specific pg binary and you will get script for that binary.

Keep note that you should apply them every time `postgresql-client-common` package is upgrading

here's how I apply them

```bash
#!/bin/bash

mv -v /usr/bin/pg_dump /usr/bin/pg_dump.orig &&
mv -v /usr/bin/psql /usr/bin/psql.orig &&
cp -v /scripts/pg_dump.sh /usr/bin/pg_dump &&
cp -v /scripts/psql.sh /usr/bin/psql &&
echo 'Setup completed.'
```

Answer (score -1):

In Ubuntu 20.04:

```
export PGCLUSTER=9.6/main    

pg_dump -V    

pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 9.6.21
```

Comment: can you elaborate your answerß